# How to avoid reflection of data entered in popup to the table before it is saved using Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an edit popup, when the popup opens and i edit, it is reflecting on the table. I must avoid the reflection, once i click on save button then only the edited part must be displayed on the table. I am able to do this only for one input, i am not getting how to carry out the same way for other 2 inputs.

//Ts

```
editTutorial(tutorial) {
  this.editTutorials.show();
  this.edit_tut = tutorial;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `tutorial` value which you sent from table into `edit_tut` varable, which is working as `two-way binding`.

**so, the data in the table is getting changed along with your input.**

The solution can be changing the `variable reference`, you can do something like,

```
editTutorial(tutorial) {
 this.editTutorials.show();
 let tut = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tutorial))
 this.edit_tut = tut;
}
```

This will change the **`value reference`** and will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have two different properties on your component, referencing to two different object instances. Few things to do:

Step 1: on clicking "edit", make a copy of the table row (all props) and put them inot the modal. Keep the reference to, e.g. table row you're editing, or _id or something.

In your case, add a property to TutorialComponent called `currentlyEditing: any`. Then, modify your editTutorial method:

```
editTutorial(tutorial) {
  this.editTutorials.show();
  this.currentlyEditting = tutorial;
}
```

Step 2: editing those should not reflect on the table. Go on and edit your thing.

Step 3: upon saving, sync your changes back to the table, or rather, to the original data set that's being displayed in the table. That's why you needed the reference from step 1.

Now, it's not clear to me if your edit_tut component is the one that saves changes. But if it is, I think everything will work as is. If not, you'd have to, after saving and response of "success", go and find the original tutorial in the `tutorials` array, and replace it with the edited component.

Comment: ya i had done those, but i want to keep the table same without reflecting when i am typing

Comment: But obviously you're not doing that. Can you show the whole component file?

Comment: ya i had updated my full ts file, please have a look